# C# Directory.GetDirectories searchPattern regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Использую:

```
string[] directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchP);
```

Вопрос, как в качестве параметра searchP использовать регулярное выражение? или что-то что поможет вывести каталоги по маске `@"!_*"`

Comment: маска `"!_*"` - это каталоги начинающиеся с `!_` ? тогда просто передавайте ее как параметр `searchP`

Comment: это каталоги начинающиеся с "не" _*

Comment: Строка, которая не начинается с `_*` - `!dirname.StartsWith("_*")`. Не нужно тут регулярное выражение. А оно выглядит как `@"^(?!_\*)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать следующий подход:

```cs
var directoryList = new DirectoryInfo(path)
    .EnumerateDirectories()
    .Where(dirInfo => Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, searchPattern))
    .ToArray();
```

Отфильтровываем папки по маске с помощью LINQ и стандартного Regex.

Comment: Regex searchP = new Regex(@"[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var directoryList = new DirectoryInfo(path)
                .EnumerateDirectories()
                .Where(dirInfo => Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, searchP)).ToArray(); ругается на Ошибка 3 Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex" в "int" невозможно 
Ошибка 2 Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(string, int)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Comment: @WizarD51 Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, searchP) зачем вы передаете туда объект Regex? Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, @"[a-z]") по идее надо

Comment: На выходе имеем полный список каталогов, что бы мы не указали в searchPattern. Получается значение параметра во внимание не принимаются. Остаются каталоги вида "_test@".

Comment: Код целиком:      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             getCatalogList(@"\\ip\aptpost", @"[a-z]");
         }

         public void getCatalogList(string path, string searchP)
        {

            DirectoryInfo[] directoryList = new DirectoryInfo(path)
               .EnumerateDirectories()
               .Where(dirInfo => Regex.IsMatch(dirInfo.Name, searchP))
               .ToArray();

            foreach (var dir in directoryList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dir);
            }
        }

Comment: @WizarD51 `^[a-z]$` - иначе у вас match отрабатывает на часть имени каталога

Comment: @PashaPash А если быть точным то ^[^_*] исключение лучше чем правило, я думаю. Спасибо большое)